# How do I use Realm in a Swift Playground?

Tags: ios, xcode, realm

So, I'm pretty new to XCode development, but I've read the documentation on [how to import third party frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/ImportFramework.html) into a Playground in XCode 7.1.1, and the documentation on how to [get started with Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started), using the Dynamic Framework method of installation.

At this point I have a workspace that contains an iOS project, the two .framework folders required by Realm, and a Playground project.  I have built the workspace without errors.

I figured going through some of the Realm examples in the Playground would be a great way to get going, but doing a simple:

```
import RealmSwift
```

results in a "No such module 'RealmSwift' error.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you install Realm with Cocoapods ?

Comment: No, as I said in the question I installed it with the Dynamic Framework method listed in the Realm docs.  I've never used CocoaPods.

Comment: @SamuelBellerose I have to give you credit, your question made me try with Cocoapods and I was able to get it working that way.  If you write an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install Realm with [Cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html).

One good practice to adopt is using Cocoapods when using other librairies like this one when they support it. That way you always have control on the version you're using of this library.

Comment: Thanks.  I use package managers in other languages, etc; not sure why it didn't occur to me to use one in iOS too. :{  Worked like a charm, though.

Answer (score 3):

Update: Realm Swift works with Swift Playgrounds now. You'll find an example in Realm's release zips ([direct download](https://static.realm.io/downloads/swift/latest)).

---

Realm doesn't support Swift Playgrounds at the moment: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/938

Comment: That issue has been solved. They say you can run Realm in a Swift playground now

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while playing with `RealmSwift` on a `Playground`. I create it under a `single view iOS` application. Fixed it after building my main target, as creates the `dynamic framework` to be linked into the `Playground`.

Working fine with `Cocoapod` installation, `Swift 4.2`, & `Xcode 10.1`
Try it yourself. https://github.com/sauvikdolui/RealmExploration

[image: SwiftPlayGround with RealmSwift]